# getting count(*) using createSQLQuery in hibernate?

Tags: sql, hibernate, count

I have several sql queries that I simply want to fire at the database.
I am using hibernate throughout the whole application, so i would prefer to use hibernate to call this sql queries.

In the example below i want to get count + name, but cant figure out how to get that info when i use createSQLQuery().

I have seen workarounds where people only need to get out a single "count(*)" from the result, but in this case I am using count(*) + a column as ouput

```
SELECT count(*), a.name as count FROM user a
WHERE a.user_id IN (SELECT b.user_id FROM user b)
GROUP BY a.name
HAVING COUNT(*) BETWEEN 2 AND 5;
```

fyi, the above query would deliver a result like this if i call it directly on the database:

```
1, John
2, Donald
1, Ralph
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cheers for the info Thomas, worked wonderful for generating objects

the problem i had with my initial query was that "count" was a reserved word :P
when i changed the name to something else it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can use

```
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT count(*) as num, a.name as name FROM user a WHERE a.user_id IN (SELECT b.user_id FROM user b) GROUP BY a.name HAVING COUNT(*) BETWEEN 2 AND 5;";

query.addScalar("num", Hibernate.INTEGER).addScalar("name", Hibernate.STRING); 
// you might need to use org.hibernate.type.StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER / STRING 
// for Hibernate v3.6+, 
// see https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-5138

List<Object> result = query.list();
// result.get(2*i + 0) -> i-th row num
// result.get(2*i + 1) -> i-th row name
```

I'm using this in case of time-pressure, imo much faster to code then creating your own beans & transformers.

Cheers!

Jakub

Answer (score 0):

If your SQL statement looks like this `SELECT count(*) as count, a.name as name...` you could use `setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(YourSimpleBean.class))` on your `Query`.
Where `YourSimpleBean` has the fields `Integer count` and `String name` respectively the setters `setCount` and `setName`.
On execution of the query with `query.list()` hibernate will return a List of YourSimpleBeans.